# webkit - width and height of html elements

Tags: android, webkit

How do i get the height and width of html elements (ListBox) in webkit ? I am working on Android browser. Any pointers on where to look will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question :

drawCursorPostamble() of webview.cpp has m_ring.m_bounds variable which holds the height and width of html elements